# How to load environment variable from azure key-vault in docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, azure-keyvault, airflow-2.x

Here I want to load the sql connection string from azure keyvault.

```
version: '3'
    x-airflow-common:
      &airflow-common
      image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.2.4-python3.8}
      # build: .
      environment:
        &airflow-common-env
        AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
        AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: mysql+mysqldb://airflow_user:airflow_pass@host.docker.internal:3306/airflow_db
        AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+mysqldb://airflow_user:airflow_pass@host.docker.internal:3306/airflow_db
        AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
        AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: '
```

Answer (score 0):

you need add to enviroment variables

> AIRFLOW__SECRETS__BACKEND : airflow.providers.microsoft.azure.secrets.azure_key_vault.AzureKeyVaultBackend
> AIRFLOW__SECRETS__BACKEND_KWARGS : '{"connections_prefix=AIRFLOW-CONNECTIONS;variables_prefix=AIRFLOW-VARIABLES;vault_url=https://kvurl.vault.azure.net/"}'